# Why does Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API) take so long to deploy via ARM template?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Why does Azure Cosmos DB take so long to deploy? When I tried deploying Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API) via ARM template, it took ~20 min for deployment to complete. Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deployment for a new Cosmos account requires involves multiple underlying resources and there are a number of steps involved that must be done in series to provision and connect these resources before the account is ready to accept requests.

Things that can impact provision time include, number child resources (databases, containers), number of regions and amount of throughput. In addition there can be other factors as well including the number of control plane operations overall in a region.

All that said, we are working on optimizations designed to reduce the amount of time it takes to provision new Cosmos DB accounts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Subsequent deploys, even when all the resources are created, are still quite slow - but only for Cosmos as compared to lots of other resources.

Comment: Depending on what you are updating, such as large scale up, this still and will always take some time.

Comment: I'm saying even just a small hello world account with a database and a container will be slow to run arm on even if there are no changes to subsequent applications of the template

Answer (score 0):

I just provisioned a new Cosmos DB today and it took a little less than 10 minutes.  East US region.

Comment: We're shooting to get this below 2 minutes this calendar year.